# gfortran compile object file error crt1.o: In function `_start':

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, fortran, gfortran

I have compiled a fortran file and an object file created.After that i tried to execute the object file but an error appears.The OS is Ubuntu and the error is below:

To compile the source file

```
gfortran -O3 reader.f iotools.c -o reader.x
```

To execute object file

```
gfortran reader.o
```

And the error

> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In
>   function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
>   reader.o: In function `MAIN__': fort77-2624-1.c:(.text+0xf): undefined
>   reference to`ireadc_' fort77-2624-1.c:(.text+0x278): undefined
>   reference to `s_wsle' fort77-2624-1.c:(.text+0x291): undefined
>   reference to`do_lio' fort77-2624-1.c:(.text+0x2aa): undefined
>   reference to `do_lio' fort77-2624-1.c:(.text+0x2c3): undefined
>   reference to`do_lio' fort77-2624-1.c:(.text+0x2c8): undefined
>   reference to `e_wsle' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

reader.f file

```
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
C  Basic fortran (and c tools) code to read fMRI images
C  Compile linux:g77 -O3 reader.f iotools.c -o reader.x
c  In Cygwin compile as : (to prevent max memory bug)
c  g77 -o reader.x -Wl,--stack,8388608 reader.f iotools.c
c   Execute:  reader.x < imagename.img
c   where "imagename.img" is a huge image fmri file
c------------------------------------------------------
c   Standard output: the full correlation matrix
c------------------------------------------------------
      parameter(maxsites=147456,maxtime=400,mintime=1)
      real a(maxsites*maxtime), b(maxsites*maxtime)
      real*8 ax, sxx(maxsites), sxy, r
      integer iflag(maxsites)

c....   Read image file into a
      i=ireadc(a,4*maxsites*maxtime)
      do ix=1, maxsites
        do it=1, maxtime
      b((ix-1)*maxtime+ it) = a((it-1)*maxsites + ix)
        enddo
      enddo

        do ix=1, maxsites
        iflag(ix)=0
        ax=0.d0
        sxx(ix)=0.d0
            do it=mintime, maxtime
            ax=ax + dble(b((ix-1)*maxtime + it))
            enddo   
        ax=ax/dfloat(1+maxtime-mintime)! mean activity for this voxel
        if(ax.gt.7000.d0.and.ax.lt.14000) then
          iflag(ix)=1                   ! flag the usefull voxels
          do it=mintime, maxtime
        ic=(ix-1)*maxtime + it
        b(ic)   =  b(ic) - ax
        sxx(ix) = sxx(ix) + dble(b(ic)*b(ic))
          enddo 
        endif
      enddo 
c--------------------------------------------------------------
       do l1=1, maxsites-1
         if(iflag(l1).eq.1) then
      do l2=l1+1, maxsites
        if(iflag(l2).eq.1) then
              sxy=0.d0
          do it=mintime, maxtime
            ic1 = (l1-1)*maxtime + it
            ic2 = (l2-1)*maxtime + it
            sxy = sxy + dble(b(ic1)*b(ic2))
          enddo
          r=sxy/dsqrt(sxx(l1)*sxx(l2))!linear l1-l2 correlation
          write(*,*) l1,l2,r
        endif
      enddo
    endif
      enddo


      end
```

Comment: The source file and the commands where given from the professor.So i should be gfortran -c -O3 reader.f iotools.c -o reader.x ?

Comment: That does not really matter, clearly they are wrong or you copied them wrong. Is there a main program in your code? Or a main function? How does the code look like?

Comment: Yes, you should have the `-c` flag there AND `-o reader.o`.  OR you should skip the second command.

Comment: gfortran -c reader.o ?

Comment: NO, not at all.

Comment: Your edit changed the question too drastically. Please do not do that. If you want to ask a new qurstion, open a new post. If you want to respond, write some comments or add some (but not too much) additional material.

Comment: I am trying to improve the questions because i am banned.I have many downvoted questions and i am trying to change that.But i don't know how to do it properly

Comment: You made this one worse, not better. Keep this one as it is, it is not bad. Concentrate on the downvoted ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly do not *execute* an object .o file. You link it to create an executable file.

But Notice you do not create the `reader.o` file, you create a `reader.x` file in:

```
gfortran -O3 reader.f iotools.c -o reader.x
```

With this command an executable file `reader.x` should be created and you should be able to execute it. There is no second `gfortran` command.

OR

You can do it in two steps. First compile and then link

```
gfortran -c -O3 reader.f iotools.c -o reader.o

gfortran reader.o
```

In this case the second command creates an executable file called `a.out`.

Both ways are possible.

These are absolute basics, please do some study first before attempting more. Read a tutorial, search among the questions there. There are many very similar questions here. I answered here just to clear your specific confusions which might not be that directly clear from some duplicates.

Comment: Execute:  reader.x < imagename.img where "imagename.img" is a huge image fmri file. How i will do that?

Comment: By writing `reader.x < imagename.img` at the command line. Have you used Linux before? These are **absolute** basics. There is no place to teach you those here. You have to study the basics first, really.

Comment: I have executed reader.x < imgNAme.img but error appears reader.x: command not found

Comment: You need `./reader.x`. Make sure you are in the right directory and `reader.x` exists. This is my last comment. You *must* study Linux basics first. Take a tutorial on youtube or read something.